# React Native app work on both ios and android

Tags: react-native

Making an app to work on both android and ios.  For the IOS version I want to use NavigatorIOS and for the android I want to use just Android.
How do I only use the correct navigator depending on the device?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Platform via the React `Platform` module:

```
var Platform = require("react-native").Platform;
if (Platform.OS === "ios") { }
else if (Platform.OS === "android") { }
```